# Fast way for character matching in R

Tags: r, character, match, grepl

I'm trying to find whether `vector` of `characters` maps to another another, and looking for a fast way of doing it in `R`.

Specifically, my character alphabet is amino acids:

```
aa.LETTERS <- c('G','P','A','V','L','I','M','C','F','Y','W','H','K','R','Q','N','E','D','S','T')
```

I have a vector of peptide and protein sequences:

```
set.seed(1)
peptides.vec <- sapply(1:100,function(p) paste(aa.LETTERS[sample(20,ceiling(runif(1,8,12)),replace=T)],collapse=""))
proteins.vec <- sapply(1:1000,function(p) paste(aa.LETTERS[sample(20,ceiling(runif(1,200,400)),replace=T)],collapse=""))
```

I want to try and see if for each peptide sequence in `peptides.vec` if it exists in any sequence in `proteins.vec`.

This is one of the obvious ways of doing it:

```
mapping.mat <- do.call(rbind,lapply(peptides.vec,function(p){
   grepl(p,proteins.vec)
}))
```

Another one is using the `Biostrings` `Bioconductor` package:

```
require(Biostrings)
peptides.set <- AAStringSet(x=peptides.vec)
proteins.set <- AAStringSet(x=proteins.vec)
mapping.mat <- vcountPDict(peptides.set,proteins.set)
```

Both are slow for the dimensions I'm working with:

```
> microbenchmark(do.call(rbind,lapply(peptides.vec,function(p){
   grepl(p,proteins.vec)
 })),times=100)
Unit: milliseconds
                                                                             expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 do.call(rbind, lapply(peptides.vec, function(p) {     grepl(p, proteins.vec) })) 477.2509 478.8714 482.8937 480.4398 484.3076 509.8098   100
> microbenchmark(vcountPDict(peptides.set,proteins.set),times=100)
Unit: milliseconds
                                    expr    min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 vcountPDict(peptides.set, proteins.set) 283.32 284.3334 285.0205 284.7867 285.2467 290.6725   100
```

Any idea how to get this done faster?

Comment: Off the top of my head (no testing), adding a `fixed = TRUE` generally gives a good speed boost. See also the "stringi" package.

Comment: (Not including spaces in your code, on the other hand, does not improve its performance.)

Comment: Actually, depending on the nature of the actual data you're working with, in some cases, `funBASE_2` might be faster -- at least that's what I'm getting with some tests....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, adding `fixed = TRUE` will lead to some performance improvement, and "stringi" is likely to give a good boost too.

Here are some tests:

```
N <- as.integer(length(proteins.vec))

funOP <- function() {
  do.call(rbind, lapply(peptides.vec, function(p) grepl(p, proteins.vec)))
}

funBASE_1 <- function() {
  # Just adds "fixed = TRUE"
  do.call(rbind, lapply(peptides.vec, function(p) grepl(p, proteins.vec, fixed = TRUE)))
}

funBASE_2 <- function() {
  # Does away with the `do.call` but probably won't improve performance
  vapply(peptides.vec, function(x) grepl(x, proteins.vec, fixed = TRUE), logical(N))
}

library(stringi)
funSTRINGI <- function() {
  # Should be considerably faster
  vapply(peptides.vec, function(x) stri_detect_fixed(proteins.vec, x), logical(N))
}

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(funOP(), funBASE_1(), funBASE_2(), funSTRINGI())
# Unit: milliseconds
#          expr        min         lq      mean     median         uq       max neval
#       funOP() 344.500600 348.562879 352.94847 351.585206 356.508197 371.99683   100
#   funBASE_1() 128.724523 129.763464 132.55028 132.198112 135.277821 139.65782   100
#   funBASE_2() 128.564914 129.831660 132.33836 131.607216 134.380077 140.46987   100
#  funSTRINGI()   8.629728   8.825296   9.22318   9.038496   9.444376  11.28491   100
```

Go "stringi"!

Comment: Would you consider using a multi-core version? though proteins.vec in reality is pretty large

Comment: @dan, I've honestly not had the experience, but I suppose it would be a good candidate for something like this.